# Audio record with Gracenote SDK android

Tags: android, audio, record, gracenote

I'm currently developing an android app using Gracenote SDK.
I want to identify music by listening a sample, so I followed everything on page 99 of the developers guide ("identifying Streaming music).
But I have a problem when I want to initialize the microphone.
I properly set the permissions, give permissions to the app (in the smartphone).

I'll be glad if someone could help me.
Thank you for reading.

Here is the error that I received.

```
W/System.err: com.gracenote.gnsdk.GnException: Failed to initialize audio source
W/System.err:     at com.gracenote.gnsdk.gnsdk_javaJNI.GnMusicIdStream_audioProcessStart__SWIG_0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.gracenote.gnsdk.GnMusicIdStream.audioProcessStart(GnMusicIdStream.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.musimap.trackproperties.GraceNoteTest$2.onClick(GraceNoteTest.java:115)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

My code

```
 IGnMusicIdStreamEvents musicStreamEvent = new IGnMusicIdStreamEvents() {
        @Override
        public void musicIdStreamProcessingStatusEvent(GnMusicIdStreamProcessingStatus gnMusicIdStreamProcessingStatus, IGnCancellable iGnCancellable) {
            Log.d("Processing", "yessir");
        }

        @Override
        public void musicIdStreamIdentifyingStatusEvent(GnMusicIdStreamIdentifyingStatus gnMusicIdStreamIdentifyingStatus, IGnCancellable iGnCancellable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void musicIdStreamAlbumResult(GnResponseAlbums gnResponseAlbums, IGnCancellable iGnCancellable) {
            Log.d("album", gnResponseAlbums.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void musicIdStreamIdentifyCompletedWithError(GnError gnError) {
            Log.d("error identification", gnError.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void statusEvent(GnStatus gnStatus, long l, long l1, long l2, IGnCancellable iGnCancellable) {

        }
    };

    try {

        mic = new GnMic();
        streamMusic = new GnMusicIdStream(user, GnMusicIdStreamPreset.kPresetMicrophone, musicStreamEvent);
        streamMusic.options().lookupData(GnLookupData.kLookupDataContent, true);
        streamMusic.options().lookupData(GnLookupData.kLookupDataSonicData, true);
        streamMusic.options().resultSingle(true);

    } catch (GnException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mic.sourceInit();
            try {
                streamMusic.audioProcessStart(mic);
                streamMusic.identifyAlbumAsync();
            } catch (GnException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

And finally my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Were you able to run the sample app and test the recognition?

Comment: I tried to use the sample but the app is too buggy. I can't launch recognition.

Comment: Actually i can't use it because of my client id. Here is the message that i receive on the log. "User Create New: client id 'MYCLIENTID' not supported by current license, GCSL Datatypes"

Comment: Please post a comment on Gracenote Developer Forum under the topic  GNSDK with the error message. Someone will assist you from there.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your problem with the client id, I think I ran into a similar before and the reason was I was using an old version of the app with the client ID I have. The current version expects the following three things:

1. gnsdkClientId
2. gnsdkClientTag
3. license.txt

The sample app should be working once you input the first two in MainActivity.java and add the license.txt in the assets folder. The sample app uses Eclipse, you can refer an Android Studio version here: https://github.com/kevguy/GracenoteSDKSample